# Is it possible to get known something about the class that contain object of another class, only from this object?

Tags: c#

I have a class, let's say A. And have an another class，let's say B. Inside of A class I'm creating an object of B class, for example b. 
So is it possible somehow to get known about A class, if I get only b (object of B class) ? Like can i get known where b was created?
Cause i want to work with A class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built-in that lets you get a reference to the instance of A that created the instance of B. But you can do it yourself with a little code by passing `this` to B in the constructor.

```
class A
{
    protected readonly B _b;

    public A()
    {
        _b = new B(this);
    }
}

class B
{
    protected readonly A _a;

    public B(A a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    public A GetCreator()
    {
        return _a;
    }
}
```

In this code, `GetCreator()` returns the instance of A that created the instance of B.

Comment: And also wanted to ask, it's good practice to use ”protected readonly” when we working with class inside another class? I'm asking just because to want improve quality of my code, and make it more like a standard :)

Comment: It's good practice to use `readonly` on fields that aren't supposed to change after the object is created (a.k.a. are immutable). And it's a good practice not to make fields public unless absolutely necessary; protected is a decent alternative. I'm in the habit of making fields `protected readonly` by default and loosening up the restrictions only when I figure out it's needed.